# WBADMIN is not creating the etl file in C:\Windows\Logs\WindowsServerBackup

Tags: windows, batch-file, backup, windows-server-2016

We have a system backup process which will create the backup process of all drives. The command is

```
WBADMIN START BACKUP -backupTarget:\\%servername%\sysBackup -include:C:,D:,E:,F: -systemState -quiet -vssFULL
```

In **Windows 2008 Server** this command is working fine and it is creating the **Wbadmin*.etl** files in **C:\Windows\Logs\WindowsServerBackup**.

But when we execute the same command (Both as Administrator) in **Windows 2016 Server**, the **Wbadmin*.etl** file is not getting generated in the above folder and the process is failing since the **etl** is not available.

Can anybody help me out to sort out this issue? Any help will be much appreciated.

Please let me know if the question is not clear or you need any further information.

Comment: No idea why somebody marked this question for closing. If they find this as not relevant, please share the information. It will be helpful

Comment: And it is not generating any error messages when you execute this from a cmd prompt?

Comment: Are you able to run `Wbadmin.msc`.

Comment: @Squashman Able to run the WBADMIN command from the command prompt and is generating the backup for all the drives. But the etl will be generated for Windows Server Backup and that is not getting generated. Will the wbadmin.etl be generated in a different path other than C:\Windows\Logs\WindowsServerBackup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got the solution from the Microsoft Support. In Windows 2012 and 2016, the `WBAdmin.etl` has been replaced by `WBEngine.etl`. Modified the code accordingly and the process is working fine now.